# How can I customize Hue for Hadoop

Tags: html, hadoop, hue, mapr

I am using the web UI Hue with Hadoop for the purpose of giving users ability to browse and download data. However, I do not want all the functionality of Hue, we have no need to provide capabilities to write queries, browse tables or make changes to the file system. Therefore I would like to make changes to the Hue UI to remove the unnecessary options.

My question is where can I find the files which Hue uses to serve content (i.e. the HTML, CSS, JS). I tried a "find . -name *.html" in the Hue installation directory and couldn't find anything. I am using MapR Hadoop and the installation directory is at /opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.6.0. Does anybody know where I can find the files I need to edit to customize Hue, or how I might be able to find them?

Comment: Hue is a open-source application, so the repository https://github.com/cloudera/hue may be a good starting point to find this kind of information.

Answer (score 0):

These blog posts documents how to just disable some apps:

- http://gethue.com/solr-search-ui-only/
- http://gethue.com/how-to-manage-permissions-in-hue/

For developing you could start with:

- http://cloudera.github.io/hue/docs-3.7.0/sdk/sdk.html
- http://gethue.com/how-to-build-hue-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/

Comment: Thanks, that solr link is what I needed and gets me almost where I need to be. I want to provide only the filebrowser app but a stripped down version of it, minus some of the features that make changes to HDFS (i.e. we want a read only filebrowser). Any idea where I can find the file I need to edit to remove these buttons/UI elements?

Comment: Hi Romain, I noticed you are a contributor on Hue. I've encountered a couple of bugs I'd like to report.

1. When I create a user in Hue, I am able to give it superuser status. However when I import a user from LDAP, I am unable to give it superuser status (trying to update user with superuser has no effect, no "user information updated" message.


2. When using the default authentication backend, when I create a new user that user is unable to access the filebrowser, with message:
IOException: Error getting user info for current user, <username> (error 500)

Comment: 3. I want to import all users in a given LDAP group. However, in the dialog for add/sync LDAP group, when I give a group and check "Import new members" and "Import new members from all subgroups", the group is created in Hue but with no members. Further syncing does not import the users in the group. I am using Hue 3.6.0

Comment: To clarify number 2, when I switch to LDAP authentication and login as imported LDAP users, they are able to access the filebrowser, and I am confident I have set the right proxy settings as I followed the config instructions exactly, found here: http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Configuring+Hue+3.x

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that serves my needs partially, will probably prove useful to others. A Hue admin can set up permissions on a per group basis for the various apps in Hue. We can provide access to an app but we can't say it should be read-only, but it's a good place to start. More info: http://gethue.com/how-to-manage-permissions-in-hue/